# Loading local `maven` repository path for `buildscript` dynamically

Tags: maven, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, properties-file

I tried to find an appropriate solution for mentioned problem but couldn't find a way out so far, hence posting here to get some correct and precise solution to the problem.

I have included app `build.gradle` in code versioning being that there are often changes in `build.gradle` (at plugins dependency levels) I need this file to be tracked in versions - cutting long story short. Now, being every team member having different location for a following specified dependency - I tried to load this from my `customLocalPaths.properties` but loading variables from `.properties` file doesn't seem to work here. The `url` property listed below only seems to accept plain string.

```
buildscript{
  repositories{
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven{
      url 'D:\\android_workspace_dependencies\\My_XYZ_dependency\\lib'  // <-- need to make this path dynamic
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how can I make the `url` path dynamic (like load it from a variable) instead of having it static string. I use to get unable to resolve path kind of error.

> Note: The `.properties` file works fine. I am using other variables from same `.properties` file in my app `build.gradle` without any issues. I also tried to load partial path i.e. single directory name but in vain.

Comment: Still waiting for the answer specific to the posted problem, may be from a document reference whether this is possible or not.

Comment: I think solutions described below should work . please check

Comment: Really excited to try your solution, though didn't tried it - but I hope this will work. After verifying this (in next few days) I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to resolve dependencies from a local libs directory, you should use the [flat directory repository type](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:flat_dir_resolver) and not a `maven` repository.

To solve your specific problem, here are at least two simple solutions based on standard Gradle features:

#### Solution 1 - use [Init Script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html)

The Init Script feature allows you to customize Gradle execution based on current build environment. Each team member could declare their specific local repository in their local Init script, as follows:

*$USER_HOME/.gradle/init.gradle*

```
allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs "c:/DEV/libs"
            }
            // or with local mavel repo:
            // maven { url  "c:/DEV/libs"  }
        }
    }
}
```

The project build script will then contain only common/shared repositories

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript{
  repositories{
    google()
    jcenter()    
  }
}
```

#### Solution 2 - use [Gradle user properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties)

You can use a Gradle property to configure the repository url/path, and let team members provide this property value in their user-specific `gradle.properties` file:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()  
        if (project.hasProperty("myLocalLibRepo")) {
            flatDir {
                dirs myLocalLibRepo
            }
            // or with local mavel repo:
            //  maven { url  myLocalLibRepo  }
        }
    }
}
```

Team member's properties file:

**$USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties**

`myLocalLibRepo=c:/DEV/libs`

Answer (score 0):

Usually, inside a company you run a Nexus or Artifactory server for the artifact. This the place to put your dependencies, and you need no more local paths.

Comment: Can you please refer to some tutorial how to setup an artifact server (Ubuntu). 
Furthermore, would be nice if you have any idea how to address the dynamic path issue temporarily.

Comment: Google "sonatype nexus" or "jfrog artifactory" They both have free versions.

Comment: Still waiting for the answer specific to the posted problem, may be from a document reference whether this is possible or not.